# How to Upload a blob to windows azure by splitting it into chunks and calling PutBlockList using REST and PHP

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage

Please can someone post some code or give a reference on how we can upload a blob to azure storage  by splitting it into chunks and calling PutBlockList using REST and PHP. I have a reference to the same using .NET code here http://wely-lau.net/2012/02/26/uploading-big-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-with-putlistblock/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Windows Azure SDK for PHP: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php especially this: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php. You could either use the SDK as is or look at the code to understand how blob upload is implemented.

Comment: The BlobRestProxy does not contain the PutBlock or PutBlockList methods

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with PHP at all but if you follow the code in createBlobBlock() and commitBlobBlocks() functions, I'm sure you'll find how it is done. From what I understand of REST API, I believe createBlobBlock implements PutBlock and commitBlobBlocks implement PutBlockList functionality. HTH.