# Uploading Large Files into Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure

I am uploading 10MB files into Azure Blob Storage by using `uplaodfilestream()`. I am getting the following error:

> Operation Timeout within the specified time

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

As the error states, your upload operation is timing out. This could happen because of many reasons but primarily this would happen over slow Internet connection as you're trying to send large data. First thing you would need to do is check your Internet connectivity.

One possible thing you could do is instead of uploading this 10 MB file in one go, break them into chunks (`blocks`) and upload those blocks. Assuming you're using .Net storage client library, look at the following functions: [`CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblock.aspx) and [`CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblocklist.aspx). To learn more about blocks, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx.

Comment: See this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612325/how-to-upload-large-block-blobs-with-the-azure-php-sdk-by-chunking-them